# How To Connect C# with ACAD 2010

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

Work on vs2008 C#, Need help to connect with autocad 2010, I follow the following steps to connect but it gives me an error.

I have to add a reference, so I go to references>>add reference>>[COM TAB]>>Autocad 2010 type library>>[OK]

I use two libraries:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common;
```

And then I use the following code to connect with AutoCAD 2010:

```
namespace Sample_CSharp_Acad_connect
{


 class Program
    {
        private static IAcadApplication oAcadApp = null;
        private static string sAcadID = "AutoCAD.Application.18";

        static void Main()
        {
            try  //get a running AutoCAD instance if avaialbale
            {
                oAcadApp = (IAcadApplication)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(sAcadID);
            }
            catch(Exception) //none found so start a new instance
            {
                System.Type AcadProg = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(sAcadID);
                oAcadApp = (IAcadApplication)System.Activator.CreateInstance(AcadProg);
            }
            if (oAcadApp != null)
            {
                oAcadApp.Visible = true; //could leave this false to hide Acad from the user
                //do whatever with Acad
                //oAcadApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Error message : **error in getting object class COM for component CLSID**
[image]

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi thanks for reply ,error in getting object class COM for component CLSID

Comment: It looks like the AutoCAD type library is not properly registered. Can you try running `regsrv32` on `Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\acax18enu.tlb` (or your equivalent localized version)?

Comment: The error code is "Server execution failed".  It couldn't get AutoCAD started, pretty unclear why.  Is it actually installed?

Answer (score 1):

COM? Don't do it.

AutoCAD has a .NET API. See http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1911627&siteID=123112 for resources from Autodesk. Also see the wiki here for more info and links galore: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info

Answer (score 0):

How do you run this code? Is it an exe file? As far as I know, it is not so easy to control AutoCAD using an external progam. There are often lizening issues which prevent such operations.

It might be easier to access AutocAD functionality using a DLL. In that case the object model of AutoCAD can be accessed directly:

```
Dim theApp as Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplications = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication()
Debug.Print(theApp.Caption)
```

The SDK contains a lot of samples for DLLs which can be loaded into AutoCAD.

**And: If it isn't really necessary, consider using .NET!**